# SSIS without SQL Server

Tags: c#, ssis

I got an SSIS package that imports data from an Oracle database and places it in several .CSV files that are to be used by other programs.

In debugging it works fine, but what i want is this program to run every 5 minutes.
How can this be accomplished? What i was hoping was a program made in C# to run the package. The reason for this is because i am sadly limited in available software (installation rights that take forever) so i pretty much only have Visual Studio with C# and SSIS installed.

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/273751/4137916), then? I'd say it's overkill to use C# for this if you're not absolutely required to, though -- you can also invoke [`dtexec`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/integration-services/packages/dtexec-utility) with a scheduled task.

Comment: @JeroenMostert i've seen dtexec come by before but honestly don't know how to use it. And all the explanations on it that i have found so far are kinda fussy for me.

Comment: If `dtexec` is too fussy, try `dtexecui`. At least it will give you an interface for configuring things at leisure. The resulting command line can then be fed to a scheduled task.

Comment: @JeroenMostert don't i need to have that installed first? 
Because as i mentioned before not able to install anything at this time :|

Comment: `dtexec` and `dtexecui` are both part of SSIS, which, according to you, is installed. If you have nothing but VS and project support for SSIS packages, then you're out of luck -- you can't automate `DtsDebugHost`, the internal thingamajag that runs packages (at least not through any documented method). You can try and see if the question I linked offers any solutions that work without an actual full installation of SSIS -- some should. However, with restrictions like these you may as well consider actually writing a C# application to do the data transfer and foregoing SSIS.

Comment: @JeroenMostert yea that's the problem. this should be a full installation of SSIS. 
I've found tutorials like this one:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/ssis-quickstart-run-dotnet?view=sql-server-2017 that show what i want to do but i can't find the right references anywhere (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc and Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

Answer (score 0):

Can versus should you do this? Can, yes probably so but as the linked answer states, this will be a violation of the licensing agreement you clicked through when you installed SSDT. Production SSIS execution is not free. Development and debugging of packages is provided for development purposes only.

Your legal choices are to deploy the packages to licensed (standard or enterprise) edition of SQL Server or rewrite your ETL process to be based on SSIS.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37245156/181965

Comment: so there is no option to have a windows form application just say "hey package start running" as it would have when debugging?

Comment: If you deploy the package to SQL Server, then you can then it's trivial to start